# Can we use LISTAGG in SAP HANA and Oracle?

Tags: oracle, hana, listagg

I want to migrate the data from SAP HANA to Oracle. But I have implemented some views using `STRING_AGG` in SAP HANA. Can we use `LISTAGG` for those implemented views in SAP HANA so that migration process will be easy. If possible please give an example. If not require advice.

I have used `STRING_AGG` in SAP HANA which made it is easier to summarize the data using '`,`'. But I later found out that `STRING_AGG` is not available in Oracle. So I want to choose the equivalent of `STRING_AGG` for Oracle. I tried implementing `LISTAGG` in SAP HANA but it is saying

> Output: invalid name of function or procedure: LISTAGG:

Example query:

```
LISTAGG(CASE WHEN v1.OFFICE_ID in(4,5,6,7,8) THEN v1.ITEM_PDT_ID 
WHEN v1.office_id IS NULL THEN v1.ITEM_PDT_ID ELSE 0 END,', ') AS "ITEM_PDT_ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

Which Oracle database version do you use? `LISTAGG` was introduced in (I believe) 11gR2 so - if you're using lower version than that, it (obviously) won't work.

```
SQL> SELECT LISTAGG (e.ename, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY e.ename) employees
  2    FROM emp e
  3   WHERE e.deptno = 10;

EMPLOYEES
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLARK, KING, MILLER

SQL>
```

---

If you search the Internet, you might find another function - `WM_CONCAT`. It is **undocumented** so you shouldn't use it; besides, Oracle *removed* it from Oracle 12c (and newer versions), but works in lower versions (I ran this code in 11g):

```
SQL> SELECT wm_concat (e.ename) employees
  2    FROM emp e
  3   WHERE e.deptno = 10;

EMPLOYEES
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLARK,KING,MILLER

SQL>
```

---

What you might do, is to use `XMLAGG` instead:

```
SQL> SELECT RTRIM (
  2            XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, e.ename || ', ') ORDER BY e.ename).EXTRACT (
  3               '//text()'),
  4            ', ') employees
  5    FROM emp e
  6   WHERE e.deptno = 10;

EMPLOYEES
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLARK, KING, MILLER

SQL>
```

Comment: `WITHIN GROUP` is [optional](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html) since 18c. However, it is required for deterministic result

Comment: Is it? Boy, I should *upgrade* myself. Thank you, @astentx.